# How can I get create-react-app to include a leading dot in the script path?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

When I build a project made in create-react-app and 
He generates a html file with a path without the dot. 
This is problematic because I have a blank page because of it.

I get an html file with an example of loading js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/mainsddss23ds.js"
```

but i need path with DOT, for example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/mainsddss23ds.js"
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src={require("/static/js/mainsddss23ds")}></script>` try it

Comment: Name file is generated automatically. I tried something like that, but it does not work. <script src=."%PUBLIC_URL%/main.js">

Comment: Is there some specific reasoning for this. I am not sure what we're trying to achieve here. can u eloberate a little more @konradolejnik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `"homepage": ".",` in `package.json`.

The build (`npm run build`) will output `<script src="./static/js/mains*.js" />`

The local dev server will still have `<script src="/static/js/mains*.js" />`